# Cache a single PHP file with parameters

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, php, cache

So I build a PHP script that receive some data and provides it like an API. The data doesn't changes much, but the script runs every time it's requested. Is there a way to tell Apache to cache the results of this file, so it does not get executed every time someone requests it? Important is to provide output according to the URL parameters, so that `file.php?param=test1` outputs something different then `file.php?param=test2`.
Can Apache (Apache2 especially) do this, or should I just implent it in my script myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself by building a simple PHP-Script to cache the data. I will add it here for completion.

```
<?php

    function CheckCache($request)
    {
        if(file_exists("./cache/" . escapeFileName($request)))
        {
            if ((time()-filemtime("./cache/" . escapeFileName($request)) > 12 * 3600) != true) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    function ReciveFromCache($request)
    {
        return file_get_contents("./cache/" . escapeFileName($request));
    }

    function SetCache($request, $staticContent)
    {
        $update = (array)json_decode($staticContent, true);
        $update['server']['cached'] = true;
        file_put_contents("./cache/" . escapeFileName($request), json_encode($update));
    }

    function escapeFileName($filename)
    {
        return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9_\-]/', '_', $filename);
    }
?>
```

Include it on your main part. The max-age of the cache gets set in `12 * 3600` where 3600 is the max time in seconds (One hour = 3600 secs * 12 = 12 hours).
'm using it like this:

```
function reciveFromRiot($reqURL, $urlParams = "")
{
    $api_key = "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx";
    $request = $reqURL . "?$urlParams&api_key=" . $api_key;

    if(CheckCache($request))
    {
        $response = ReciveFromCache($request);
    }
    else
    {
        $response = file_get_contents("https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/" . $request);
        $responsecode = explode(" ", $http_response_header[0])[1];

        if($responsecode != "200")
            return false;

        SetCache($request, $response);
    }

    return json_decode($response);
}
```

I'll just let it as it is as an example for the [Riot Game API](https://developer.riotgames.com/).
**Note** that there needs to be a folder *cache* at the same location as the script.

Answer (score 0):

Could you put the data that doesn't change much into a variable of the parent page and then when your script is called it only runs what it needs? Process your small script via AJAX so the page doesn't refresh every time?

Comment: This isn't the real problem. The API is semi public and I don't have to implent it in websites myself. My script acts as API, collecting data from different places and put them together for simple access. The problem is, that all the data it provides get requested everytime someone requests something from my API, which is not really necessary. I want my server to cache the data and only refreshes as specified.

Comment: Could you write your own caching mechanism so that pages where a particular output is generated (given a URL parameter) and the result (the desired output) is stored in a file that you can return

Comment: I'm currently trying. I three function: `CheckCache` which searchs for a file named the same as the request url and if its exits the modification time if its out of date. Then `reciveFromCache` which is outputing the cache and `setCache` which overwrites the old cache. Do I miss something?

Comment: I think you should be fairly good to go. Good luck.